# Perturbation of matrix SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A$ in SVD, $A = U \Sigma V^{\ast}$, I am interested in approximating the SVD of the matrix
$$\hat{A} = A + \Delta X
$$ where $\Delta \in \mathbb{R}$ is a small parameter and $X$ is a matrix.  Having looked around I have found bounds on the angles between subspaces of left and right singular vectors, but no way of approximating singular vectors.  I have also found ways of approximating the SVD of $\Delta X$ given the SVD of $\hat{A}$ but this is not what I am interested in.

Is anyone aware of a way to approximate the SVD of $\hat{A}$ given the SVD of $A$, perhaps with some assumptions about the structure of A?

Comment: the last part of your question doesn't make any sense. It is like you're saying that you don't even have information about $A$ but in the first sentence you say have the matrix $A$.

Comment: Sorry if it is unclear.  Suppose I do know the matrix $A$ and its SVD, I also know the matrix X and I want to know an approximation of the SVD of $\hat{A}$.

Comment: ok, i can work with that.